# How to debug PyQT GUI based application?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have a program written using PyQT and I have a memory issue somewhere in it and get crashes with a segmentation fault error (`Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`).

I am trying to track this down but when I try to use the debugger in PyCharm, once the GUI pops up the debugger is basically useless. Once the GUI launches and I am controlling it via clicks and input, the debugger just acts as a normal console.

Is there a better IDE for this? Or some external program I can use to monitor and find this error?

I am doing threading and I know this is the most common cause of memory issues in QT, below this is my main threading code

```
class ConsoleWindowLogHandler(logging.Handler, QObject):
sigLog = pyqtSignal(str)

def __init__(self):
    logging.Handler.__init__(self)
    QObject.__init__(self)

def emit(self, log_record):
    message = str(log_record.getMessage())
    self.sigLog.emit(message)
```

With my threaded objects being created in

```
class MainClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, log_instance=Logger()):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()
            self.bee = Worker(self.start_button_click, ())
            self.bee.finished.connect(self.reset_gui)
            self.bee.terminate()
            self.connect_bee = Worker(self.connect_button_click, ())
            self.connect_bee.finished.connect(self.conect_after_thread)
            self.connect_bee.terminate()
            consoleHandler = ConsoleWindowLogHandler()
            consoleHandler.sigLog.connect(self.ui.tb_log_window.append)
            logger_real_time.addHandler(consoleHandler)
            logger_real_time.addHandler(consoleHandler)
```

And then the threading is called from within functions that are held in 'MainClass' (these are trigged by a button click on the GUI. When the button is clicked, `start_button_pressed_threaded` gets called which starts the thread.

```
    def start_button_pressed_threaded(self):
        self.bee.start()
```

Comment: Run the code in a standard console / command-window (i.e. not an IDE), so you can see any Python traceback and/or Qt messages. If that doesn't make it obvious where the problem is, you will need to provide a proper [mre]. I suspect the issue may be related to performing GUI operations outside the main thread (which Qt does not support). However, since you omitted most of the relevant code, it's almost impossible to give a reliable diagnosis.

Comment: Also post debugging details. I guess you don't get a Python stack trace because it crashes in the native layer. So you need a native debugger such as WinDbg or Visual Studio. But I don't recommend debugging the C/C++ layer, if you don't have many experiences on it. (In many cases, you end up building Python, Qt, PyQt, etc. in debug mode.) Alternatively, just use break points and commenting part of your code in the Python layer to locate the problematic code.

Comment: What is `Worker`? Is it a QThread subclass? If it is, not only using `terminate()` is discouraged (see [the documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate) but it doesn't make any sense to call it right after creating it. I'm also afraid that not keeping a persistent reference to `consoleHandler` might be a problem (but to be sure we need a MRE as written above).